# how to get access token through Keycloak REST API

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I'm trying to get the access token  using Keycloak Rest API  in my spring boot Application
here is my URL that i passed in Postman using post method,

http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/springboot/protocol/openid-connect/token  ,

here test is my realm
and in body part as www-form-urlencoded content type, i have passed 
username,password,client_id,grant_type as password,
I have done the part in admin console also setting up realm and other things,
the response i am getting in postman is 404 not found,
the expected output is the access token.

```
----
 here is my configuration in my app
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8180/auth
keycloak.realm=springboot
keycloak.resource=springboot
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=user
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/save/*
----
```

[here is the screenshot of  response that im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ineJS.png)

Comment: Is your keycloak server reachable with `http://localhost:8180/auth`?
Have you double checked your config in general, e.g. are both your realm and your client called `springboot`? I'm guessing you are new to keycloak? If so, which did you use a tutorial or something like that for setting up your current config?

Comment: yes,I'm new to keycloak. i actually solved this issue , can you please..tell me how to create client application and set user and role through keycloak rest api?